# StringTemplate 4 and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I've just found out StringTemplate and wanted to test it in python. Does v4 work in Python (2.7/3)? Wiki is empty and I can't find any info about python port for v4 version. v3 is the only working version (in ofc Python)?

Answer (score 2):

Even if the use of a python port is in the [Doc](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST4/Introduction) as state *doru*, it seems as at time of this post, the port is not yet available.

The [strintemplate 4 download page](http://www.stringtemplate.org/download.html)
only mention Java and C#, and the [Download Repository](http://www.stringtemplate.org/download/) has only a version 3 of *PyStringTemplate* that you [find also in pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/stringtemplate3/). I have seen on the web that 
Benjamin Niemann the author and maintainer of the python port accepted to work on the port of v4, but no more!